# Altering function argument on return

Tags: maxima

Suppose the following example

```
g(x):=block([],
  x:x+1
);

xx:1$;
g(xx)$;
xx;
```

This outputs `1`. How can I have it output `2`?

**Edit:** I searched for "maxima" combined with "pass by reference" and the results don't seem to suggest that "pass by reference" is really a thing defined in Maxima but if you know what I mean, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *macro* (an utility that generates maxima code).

```
(%i1) g(x)::=buildq([x], x : x + 1) $
(%i2) a: 1 $
(%i3) g(a) $
(%i4) a ;
(%o4)                                  2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your trouble is simply that you have both % and ; in the xx assignment line.

Here's what works for me:

```
g(x):=block([],
  x:x+1
);
```

xx:1;

g(xx);